# Mapping Tkinter entry box to variable in python 3.8

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I am a complete beginner in python,I was hoping someone could help me figure out what I am trying to accomplish.

I built a small tkinter front end that will generate a string multiple times. I want the amount of times that the string is generated to be based off of an entry box. I have hit a wall.

Here is my Front End (help_FE.py)

```
from tkinter import *
import help_BE
def view_formula():
    text1.delete('1.0',END)
    text1.insert(END,help_BE.End_result)
pass

window = Tk()
window.wm_title=("Print:")
l1=Label(window,text = "Page to print:")
l1.grid(row=3, column=2)
e1 = Entry(window)
e1.grid(row=3, column=3)
text1=Text(window, height=20,width=35)
text1.grid(row=4,column=3, rowspan=10, columnspan=7, padx=5, pady=10)
sb1=Scrollbar(window)
sb1.grid(row=4,column=11,rowspan=10)
text1.configure(yscrollcommand=sb1.set)
sb1.configure(command=text1.yview)
text1.bind('<<TextboxSelect>>')
b1=Button(window, text = "Generate", width =10, command=view_formula)
b1.grid(row=3,column=6)

window.mainloop()
```

and my backend (help_BE.py)

currently, the generate button will print "Testing" 3 times, because i have set pages = 3 in the backend, but I want to be able to set pages to whatever is entered into the frontend entry box.

```
pages = 3
result=[]
def foo():
    skip_zero = pages + 1
for x in range (skip_zero):
if x==0:
continue
        result.append("Testing"+str(x))

    listToStr = ''.join([str(element) for element in result])
    full_formula = (listToStr)
return full_formula

End_result = foo()
```

Comment: You should *call* `help_BE.foo()`, perhaps passing it `pages` as a parameter, rather than using a precalculated result from that function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data inputted in the field can be accessed using the function `Entry.get()`, and you can convert the string to a number with the `int` function.
In order to get it to the backend, and in order to keep your value up to date, I would make sure that, as jasonharper mentioned, you call `foo` each time the button is pressed, passing the entry's value in as the argument `pages`. This means tweaking your code as such:

help_BE.py

```
def foo(pages):
    skip_zero = pages + 1
    for x in range (skip_zero):
        if x==0:
            continue
        result.append("Testing"+str(x))
    listToStr = ''.join([str(element) for element in result])
    full_formula = (listToStr)
return full_formula
```

help_FE.py

```
def view_formula():
    text1.delete('1.0',END)
    text1.insert(END,help_BE.foo(int(e1.get())))
```

Comment: Actually one small problem now, it will not clear the previous text when I click generate. It will just keep adding to it. It was being cleared before, with the "text1.delete('1.0',END)" .

Comment: Solve it, just added a .clear() method to my list at the beginning of the for loop .